# Зачем указывать настолько дробное число? Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, css

Привет, тут копался в кодах бутстрапа и постоянно вижу такое:

```
.row-fluid .offset10:first-child {
  margin-left: 85.1063829787234%;
  *margin-left: 84.99999999999999%;
}

.row-fluid .offset9 {
  margin-left: 78.72340425531914%;
  *margin-left: 78.61702127659572%;
}

.row-fluid .offset9:first-child {
  margin-left: 76.59574468085106%;
  *margin-left: 76.48936170212764%;
}
```

Собственно назрел вопрос для чего указывать настолько длинное дробноe число если более чем достаточно округлить до десятых ( ну край -- сотых ), или я чего то непонимаю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего, было сгенерено автоматически из величин чего-то типа y/x. В этом случае авторы просто забыли поставить  это самое округление.

Например, 85.1063829787234 - это 40/47.

Comment: есть сомнения, что в lessc есть функции округления, да и вообщем-то на конечный результат это не повлияет.

Answer (score 3):

CSS файлы Bootstrap'a генерятся автоматически утилитой LESSC на основе шаблонов (см файлы .less) отсюда и такие значения.